# Products Export Not working | Both Default export and Custom Script export

Tags: magento-1.9, session, export, timeout

I can't able to export my products both using default export and custom script export of product, Actually my site consists 1 lakh products, how can i export my products.

> error : Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate
>   89 bytes) in /home/abc/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 291

Answer (score 0):

1. Try increasing memory in php.ini and restart apache and see if that works.

`memory_limit = 16M` to your `php.ini` file

2. Try to refresh indexes in Magento in System > Index Management. Refreshing indexes helped.